# How to know when a file operation is completed in android

Tags: android, android-handler

I'm creating an app which includes file operations features like copying,moving etc,and will be done using a separate thread.
How do I know when the file operation is completed?

Comment: The thread can display a Toast() when done for instance.

Comment: @blackapps: That requires knowing when it's done which is my question.

Comment: ???? The thread will know when its ready. You were the one who waits and wants to be informed. What other scenario would there be?